# In a Durandal viewmodel, the view isn't always attached when viewAttached() called

Tags: javascript, mvvm, durandal

I have a ViewModel in Durandal that has a function `viewAttached()`.

According to [the docs](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM.html) this is supposed to be called after the view is attached to the DOM.

In my function I have a jQuery selector for an element in the View that is being attached:

```
function viewAttached() {
    console.log( $("#myViewId").length );
}
```

Most of the time I correctly get "1" printed to the console, but maybe 10% of the time I get 0. The view is not yet actually attached to the DOM.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`viewAttached` gets the produced DOM sub tree passed in as argument.

So you could either change the code to something along the line

```
function viewAttached(view) {
    console.log( $(view).length );
}
```

if you want to wrap the whole view with jQuery or to

```
function viewAttached(view) {
    console.log( $(view).find('mySubSelector').length );
}
```

if you need to work with some specific sub tree elements.

Comment: Yep that is exactly what I ended up doing. Fortunately I could since the code was my own, but there are some other jQuery libraries out there that internally use `$(...)` to do things, always assuming your elements will be on the main DOM. The inconsistency of it is what really messed me up. If it was always on or always off the DOM at least it would be consistent :)

Comment: So is your parent already in the DOM when you're trying to access it? According to docu: "This allows a controller or presenter to have direct access to the dom sub-tree to which it is bound at a point in time after it is injected into its parent."

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things to note:

1. viewAttached fires after the current module's view is attached to it's direct parent, which is NOT necessarily when it is attached to the DOM. This is an obvious limitation in some cases. For Durandal 2.0 we are adding an additional callback called documentAttached which fires when everything is attached to the page's dom.
2. viewAttached is passed the view for the current module. You should use this to provde a context to any jQuery code that you write.