# Issue with Highcharts not rendering in Durandal/Hot Towel Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts, single-page-application, durandal, hottowel

We're using HighCharts.js in a Durandal/Hot Towel template in ASP.NET MVC 4. We are simply showing a proof of concept in using a charting API for a dashboard page. However, the graph is not rendering on the page during page load.

We have a custom .js file that holds the following code (copied and pasted from HighCharts.com):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reportgraph').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});
```

And a div in an HTML view that is rendering correctly:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span12">
          <div class="widget">
               <div class="widget-header">
                    <div class="title">Highcharts</div>
               </div>
               <div class="widget-body">
                    <div id="reportgraph" style="width:100%"></div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The script bundler contains the following files:

```
.Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/highcharts.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/custom.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.debug.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/sammy-{version}.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/toastr.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/Q.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/breeze.debug.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/moment.js"));
```

Yet the graph does not render. I've been able to successfully render the graph in a Bootstrap application, working with the scripts listed above.

Is there an extra step that must be done in order to work with functions inside document.ready statements on a single page application?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a typical Durandal app there's no need to use document ready as at that point only the content of index.html (`applicationHost`) has been rendered. Everything else gets injected into the DOM by using Durandal's [composition](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/).

In order to work with these composed DOM fragments add a [viewAttached](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM/) callback in the vm that accompanies the html view. `viewAttached` gets the composed view passed in as parameter, which should be used to restrict the jQuery selector.

```
function viewAttached(view) {
    $('#reportgraph', view).highcharts({
        ...
    });
};
```

In most instances that should be sufficient to get jQuery plugins working. However in Durandal 1.2 `viewAttached` just ensures that the composed fragment is attached to its parent element not necessarily to the DOM, so you'd have to check if this is sufficient to get highcharts working. That issue will be addressed in upcoming Durandal 2.0 by introducing a [documentAttached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468900/in-a-durandal-viewmodel-the-view-isnt-always-attached-when-viewattached-call) callback.

Comment: RainerAtSpirit - thank you for the quick response. You were correct, we implemented the call in function viewAttached(view) {} call and it worked successfully.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit what about if highcharts element need to be refreshed with a new datasource? for example I have some dropdowns in my view what force to reload my chart according the selections. thank you!