# Highcharts and durandal

Tags: javascript, highcharts, typescript, durandal

I am working with duradal, what is included in hot towel template (see http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/).
So, Everything is okay when I try show the chart the first time. My chart control is declared in viewAttached method and this is working well. The issue start when I try refresh my chart according some changes in the user interface ( different selections on some dropdowns).
is there some way to refresh a chart after to render it ?

Note: bellow there is post related with render issue the first time, but this is not my problem.
[Issue with Highcharts not rendering in Durandal/Hot Towel Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287276/issue-with-highcharts-not-rendering-in-durandal-hot-towel-template)

Any clue?

Comment: Which parts of chart you need to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have tried something and failed or if you don't know where to start. But I would recommend setting up subscriptions on the Knockout observables that are backing up your dropdowns and doing your refresh from there.

For example:

```
var dropdownValue = ko.observable();
var subscription;

...

function activate() {
    subscription = dropdownValue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        // do whatever else you need to do here
        // and run redraw on the chart instance
        chart.redraw();
    });
}

function deactivate() {
    // cleanup
    subscription.dispose();
}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean with "redraw" method since highcharts doesn't have any method like that. (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)